# How to redraw and finish a control diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, diagrams, control

I'm trying to draw a block, but I don't understand the package [schemabloc](https://ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc),
I whish to quit the last block to the right and left it as the example. Perhaps this can be done with `pgfplots` and blocks, but it is supposed `schemabloc` is more handy and useful (and I want to learn to apply).

[image]

**MWE**:
I have tryed so many times to understand this package but I'm
saturated. That's because I got distracted and the code wasn't uploaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \sbEntree{E}
        \sbComp{comp}{E}
        \sbRelier[$v_s$]{E}{comp}
        \sbBloc{F}{$\alpha$}{comp}
        \sbRelier[$$]{comp}{F}
        \sbBloc[6]{int}{$\frac{1}{s}$}{F}
        \sbRelier[$v_o$]{F}{int}
        \sbRelier{F}{int}
        \sbDecaleNoeudy[4]{F}{U}
        \sbBlocr[-2]{R}{$\beta$}{U}
        \sbRelieryx{F-int}{R}
        \sbRelierxy[$v_f$]{R}{comp}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

***UPDATE***
Since its a bit bugging to understand (at least for me ) the schemabloc pack, could someone port it to any suggestion you have? Thanks

Comment: Ahhh!!, Sorry I didn't see the mwe wasnt uploaded.

Comment: plain TikZ is more convernient!

Comment: Im tinking the same.

Comment: I think you can also have a look the the Blox-manual https://ctan.org/pkg/blox ... syntax seems to be similar. // Basically you a) "place" and name blocks, b) draw connectors (Links with some labels/text) between them and to in-/outputs.

Comment: @MS-SPO I remember that package, the problem is the zip from ctan does not have the .sty file and cant installe it.

Comment: @corie, ok, understand. If you are using Miktex, it will install missing packages once you use them. Blox worked that way for me. All I have to do is to wait a little during the install.

Comment: This is a little curious to me, because when I have to install the packages manually, it always come with the .sty. Its supposed that all the distros have included these library. Perhaps Im gonna post a question about how to setup blox, in a way it seems a little more practical, (of course schemablo is very useful, but its a bit more entagled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the left lamp, Zarko used a `style`; another way is using a `pic`. Here is yet another plain TikZ way: using a usual circle `node`, and then decorate it by drawing something in the background. Using plain TikZ, you easily get full control on your figure.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\def\a{2.5} \def\b{2}

\path[nodes={minimum width=15mm, minimum height=10mm,draw,thick,fill=yellow!50}]
(0,0) node (alpha) {$\alpha$}
(0,-\b) node (beta) {$\beta$}
;
\path 
(\a,0)  node[circle,fill,inner sep=1mm] (R) {}
(-\a,0) node[circle,draw,thick,minimum size=10mm] (L) {}
;
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[gray] (L.45)--(L.-135) (L.-45)--(L.135);
\path 
(L.center) node[left,red]{$+$}
(L.center) node[below,blue]{$-$}
;
\end{scope}
\draw[->] (L)--(alpha);
\draw[->] (R.0)--+(0:1) node[above left]{$v_0$};
\draw[<-] (L.180) node[above left]{$v_s$}--+(180:1);
\draw[->] (R) |- (beta) node[pos=.5,right]{$\beta=\dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_F}$};
\draw[->] (beta) -| (L) node[pos=1,below right]{$v_f$};
\draw (alpha)--(R);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

With pure Ti*k*Z is not so difficult ... and you have absolute control over scheme. By defining common styles of scheme elements as shown in MWE below, you have uniform style for all pictures with similar content as is this simple one:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                }
\tikzset{control/.style = {% can be used in any tikzpicture in document
arr/.style = {-{Triangle[angle=45:1pt 4]}},
box/.style = {draw, semithick, fill=olive!30,
             minimum width=12mm, minimum height=9mm, outer sep=0pt},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt, outer sep=0pt,
             node contents={}},
sum/.style = {circle, draw, semithick, minimum size=6mm, outer sep=0pt,
             append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                \draw   (\LN.north west) -- (\LN.south east)
                        (\LN.north east) -- (\LN.south west);
                \node[left =-0.75mm, font=\footnotesize]  at (\LN.center) {$+$};
                \node[below=-0.50mm, font=\footnotesize]  at (\LN.center) {$-$};
                        }},
            node contents={}
            },
every edge/.append style = {draw, arr}
        }}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[control,
node distance = 4mm and 8mm,
                        ]
\coordinate (in);
\node (n1)  [sum, right=of in];
\node (n2)  [box, right=of n1]  {$\alpha$};
\node (n3)  [dot, right=of n2];
\coordinate[right=of n3] (out);
%
\node (n4)  [box, below=of n2]  {$\beta$};
%
\path   (in)    edge ["$v_s$"]      (n1)
        (n1)    edge                (n2)
        (n2)    edge [-,"$v_o$"]    (n3)
        (n3)    edge                (out);
\draw[arr]  (n3) |- (n4) node [pos=0.5,right] {$\beta=\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_\mathrm{F}}$};
\draw[arr]  (n4) -| (n1) node [pos=0.9,right] {$v_\mathrm{f}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that it is a framework that summarizes a lot of code in commands that allow to make complex drawings in a few lines, the problem of course is to understand what each command does, especially when it is in another language. what remains is brute force, and it is looking for the manual and thanks to the fact that it has codes with graphic results, you can check what each code does, line by line, that way you can understand part of the code until it gives us a useful result ; for some things that can no longer be searched or are not implemented, you can add classic code but without wasting some details such as the nodes that are created in the commands, here is an example, and the last commented lines that allow finding the nodes for do not get lost.

**RESULT:**

[image]

**USING CODE TO FIND NODES:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{C2E1D2}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \sbStyleBloc{black!80,very thick,fill=color1,text=black,inner sep=0}% modifies the style of the blocks, it can be updated on each line. page 3 of manual.
        \sbStyleLien{>=Triangle,very thick} % modifies the arrow style
        \sbEntree{E} %Macro that defines the initial point
        \sbComp*{comp}{E} %creates a "comparation" shape and node at a defined distance from the start point E.
        \sbRelier[$v_s$]{E}{comp} % Creates an arrow \macroinfrench[arrow_text]{start node name}{end node name}
        \sbBloc{block1}{$\alpha$}{comp} % Creates a block \macro{new block node name}{block text}{name of the previous block}
        \sbRelier[]{comp}{block1} % Arrow from comp to block1
        \sbSortie[4]{S}{block1} % define the output node after block 1 \macro[shift]XXXX
        \sbRelier[$v_0$]{block1}{S} % Arrow from block1 to S
        \sbDecaleNoeudy[4]{S}{U} % create a node 4 units below S with the name U
        \sbBlocr[4]{Fblock1}{$\beta$}{U} % create a feedback block. I have named it Fblock1 \macro[shift, the same value from S]XXXX
        \sbRelieryx{block1-S}{Fblock1} % arrow that goes in X and then in Y from the midpoint of block1 y S
        \sbRelierxy[$v_f$]{Fblock1}{comp} % 
        %adding other details using basic tikz code.
        \draw[fill=black] (block1-S|-S) circle (1.5pt); % adot in Vo
        \draw(comp.135) -- (comp.-45)(comp.45)--(comp.-135); % To draw a comparator symbol.
        \draw(U)++(-18pt,0) node[anchor=180]{$\beta=\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_F}$}; % draw a text from a known node
        %Some help code to find the nodes: 
%       \foreach \nodename in {E,comp,block1,S,U,Fblock1}{
%           \node[draw, circle,fill=red,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0,label={[red,label distance=-1pt]-90:\tiny\nodename}] at (\nodename.center){};
%       }   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**

I prefer to use the standalone environment that allows me to create pre-compiled tikz drawings that I then incorporate into the main document as a figure but keeping the vector format with the advantage of being able to scale it and position it in the best way like any image.

Comment: Thanks for the great advise and help, it is a great package, but its a bit complex to make it work, but with your information its a great re-start. !