# How to draw a diagram using TikZ to represent a parallel connection of two blocks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am learning TikZ to draw diagrams for LaTeX documents.. One challenge for me is to draw a block diagram using TikZ for a parallel connection of two blocks. Kindly help me with a suitable TikZ code to draw this diagram. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634367/140722

Comment: Thanks - It answered my next query - how to draw a feedback loop with TikZ - This query is about parallel connection.. These are different ways of joining control systems with transfer functions.. Your link is useful - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This diagram made using TikZ. A good practice is to define your own styles with `tikzset` and normally creating some level of flexibility with `n args` and defining a `default` style.

This is how I created the styles: `addCross`, `mySimpleArrow` and `myBlock`. These commands were written so that I can place them as the optional argument of a scope block, that is `\begin{scope}[opt args]`. Please, notice you can edit the arrow style at your will. If you want colors, just use a syntax like `mySimpleArrow={blue}{red}` instead of `mySimpleArrow` at the scope block.

The first blocks of scopes define the main nodes of the diagram, i.e., circles and squares. The last scope if responsible for drawing the connections between nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{addCross/.style n args={6}{
    minimum size={#5 mm},
    path picture={
      \draw[#6]
      (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west)
      (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.south)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$) {#1};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.west)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$)  {#2};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.north)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$) {#3};
      \node at ($(path picture bounding box.east)!0.4!(path picture bounding box.center)$)  {#4};
    }
  },
  addCross/.default={}{}{}{}{10}{}
}
\tikzset{mySimpleArrow/.style n args={2}{
    >={latex[#1]},
    every path/.style={draw=#2}
  },
  mySimpleArrow/.default={black}{black}
}
\tikzset{myBlock/.style ={
    every node/.style={rectangle,draw, text=black,
      minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm,}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, font={\Large}]
\node[draw,circle,addCross={\small$+$}{}{\small$+$}{}{10}{}] (S) at (2,0) {};

\begin{scope}[myBlock]
  \node (G1) at (0,1) {$G_1(s)$};
  \node (G2) at (0,-1) {$G_2(s)$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[mySimpleArrow]
  \path[->] (G1) -| (S) node[above, midway]{$Y_1(s)$};
  \path[->] (G2) -| (S) node[below, midway]{$Y_2(s)$};
  \path[->] (-3,0) node[above]{$U(s)$} -- ++(1,0) coordinate(U) |- (G1) node[above, midway]{$U_1(s)$};
  \path[->] (U) |- (G2) node[below, midway]{$U_2(s)$};
  \path[->] (S) -- ++(2,0) node[above]{$Y(s)$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. I'd say your image comes from a Ogata's book. I recognize the arrow style despite not reproducing it exactly at this example.

Comment: I happened to have almost the same diagram made for my material, except by the labels U1, U2, Y1 and Y2.